# How do I find a all files ending with .bpmn and replace [BUILD_VERSION] place holder with Gitlab_tag in makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, gitlab, camunda

I am trying to replace the build version in camunda with the gitlab tag version.

In my make file my code looks like this,

version:
find ./ -name “*.bpmn” -exec sed -i ‘s/versionTag=“[BUILD_VERSION]”/versionTag=$(GITLAB_TAG)/g’ {} ;

In my .bpmn files, I have this
<bpmn:process id=“documentprocess” versionTag=“[BUILD_VERSION]”>

I am getting an error find: -exec: no terminating ; or +

Could some please clarify this?
I am new to scripting.

version:
find ./ -name “*.bpmn” -exec sed -i ‘s/versionTag=“[BUILD_VERSION]”/versionTag=$(GITLAB_TAG)/g’ {} ;

And I was expected the build version to change to gitlab tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happens when you execute the `find` command from the command line (without a makefile)?

Comment: @Beta It shows me the files which ends with .bpmn

Comment: Please edit your question to use proper formatting.  Formatting of makefiles is critical so if you don't format your question properly we can't tell what might be wrong.

Comment: However I don't believe that that command actually works in the shell either.  You need to escape the `;` from the shell interpreter, using a backslash like `\;`.  Else the shell will see the semicolon as a command separator and not pass it to the `find`.

Comment: Besides the technical correct answer that you need to fix the find command ... what are you trying to achieve? Camunda will use a new revision tag for each new deployment of a changed bpmn file anyway ... the version tag should be used to indicate changes of the business features of a process, so you can see that an old instance is still running on an outdated version ... if you automate setting of the version tag, you loose this indicator ... could you explain, what you are trying to do?

Comment: @JanGalinski I am trying to update camunda version tag using Gitlab auto tags if there are differences in the .bpmn files. For now I have used this which replaces the versions from .bpmn files.  find ./ -name "*. bpmn" -exec sed -1. bak 's |" (BUILD _VERSION)" |"3.1.1"|g' {} +   However, this is just to check if it replaces the version tag and it works. I want to use git diff and gitlab tag instead of hardcoded 3.1.1 as a version number.

Comment: @MadScientist find ./ -name "*. bpmn" -exec sed -1. bak 's |" (BUILD _VERSION)" |"3.1.1"|g' {} +

Comment: Yes that will work because `+` is not special to the shell, like `;` is.